# Calculus methods and computability

Tags: computability, logical-validity

We know about calculability of a function or computability. We looks for the ability to solve a specific problem / compute a function with calculus method.

But if we define a calculus method, is there a way to find generals limits of the method  ?

Can we say that if the method can give same results as logical connective/operators, this method would solved anything computable by logical operators ?

**EDIT** :

I an other way the question could be : How can we define the "computation power" or "computability space" of a method (Turing machine, logical operators, lambda cacul, celular automaton, etc....) ?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you change it to give examples of what you mean?

Comment: @AndrejBauer edited my post, is it better ?

Comment: Yes, I think it's better, but you can also change the original question and the title. For instance, when you say "calculus method", do you mean "calculus as in mathematical analysis (derivatives, integrals)" or do you mean "calculus" in the general sense? The title is already possibly misleading, if you know how to fix it, that would be helpful.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, I mean calculus in general sense, If you have any suggestion to change title it is very welcome !

Comment: I think you might be wondering how, given a definition of some _computation model_ (e.g. a given programming language, or a class of automata possibly affecting stacks/queues/tapes/grids), we can assess its computational power, for instance comparing it against PDAs, TMs, or the like. What you call "calculus" is probably meant to be "computation". In general, there is no fast universal method to solve that: often, one tries to simulate one model inside another one to prove that the latter is at least as powerful.